# Getting unhandled Exception: Cannot hit test a render box with no size in Flutter

Tags: flutter

I am getting the above error. I am fairly new to Flutter and am maintaining code written by someone else and I can't figure out why it's giving me this error. I'm sure the solution is probably easy but this is my only hope.

Here is my code. It's a simple events application.

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      // height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.9,
      padding: EdgeInsets.all(20),
      child: Form(
        key: _formKey,
        child: ListView(
          // mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: [
            Padding(
              padding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
              child: Text(
                'CREATE EVENT',
                style: TextStyle(
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                    fontSize: 15,
                    color: Colors.grey[300]),
              ),
            ),
          Container(
            width: 50,
            height: 50,
            child: Row(
                  children: [
                    Container(
                      height: 100,
                      width: 100,
                      child: GestureDetector(
                        onTap: () async => {
                          _eventData['profile'] = await ImagePickerImpl.takeImage()
                        },
                        child: Container(
                          width: 100,
                          height: 100,
                          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10),
                          decoration: BoxDecoration(
                              shape: BoxShape.circle, color: Colors.blue[900]),
                          child: const FaIcon(
                            FontAwesomeIcons.camera,
                            color: Colors.white,
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                    Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 5.0),
                      child: TextFormField(
                        decoration: const InputDecoration(
                          labelText: 'Title',
                          border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                        ),
                        validator: (value) {
                          if (value!.isEmpty) {
                            return 'Invalid Title!';
                          }
                          return null;
                        },
                        onSaved: (value) {
                          _eventData['title'] = value!;
                        },
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
          ),
            Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 5),
              child: DropdownButtonFormField<String>(
                decoration: const InputDecoration(
                  border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                  labelText: 'Category',
                ),
                value: _type,
                items: const [
                  DropdownMenuItem(
                    value: 'CONCERT',
                    child: Text('Concert'),
                  ),
                  DropdownMenuItem(value: 'FOOD', child: Text('Food')),
                ],
                onChanged: (val) {
                  _type = val;
                },
                validator: (value) {
                  if (value == null) {
                    return 'Category is requird';
                  }
                  return null;
                },
                onSaved: (value) {
                  _eventData['type'] = value!;
                },
              ),
            ),
            Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 5),
              child: DropdownButtonFormField(
                decoration: const InputDecoration(
                  border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                  labelText: 'City',
                ),
                value: _city,
                items: const [
                  DropdownMenuItem(
                    value: 'MEKELLE',
                    child: Text('Mekelle'),
                  )
                ],
                onChanged: (val) {
                  _city = val;
                },
                validator: (value) {
                  if (value == null) {
                    return 'City is requird';
                  }
                  return null;
                },
                onSaved: (value) {
                  _eventData['city'] = value!;
                },
              ),
            ),
            Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(5),
              child: Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                children: [
                  Row(
                    children: [
                      Text(
                        _eventData["startDate"] != null
                            ? "${_eventData["startDate"].month}/${_eventData["startDate"].day}/"
                                "${_eventData["startDate"].year}"
                            : 'Start Date',
                        style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18),
                      ),
                      TextButton(
                        onPressed: () async {
                          var val = await presentDatePicker(context);
                          if (val != null) {
                            setState(() {
                              _eventData["startDate"] = val;
                            });
                          }
                        },
                        child: Container(
                          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10),
                          decoration: BoxDecoration(
                              color: Colors.blue[900], shape: BoxShape.circle),
                          child: const FaIcon(
                            FontAwesomeIcons.calendarAlt,
                            color: Colors.white,
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                  Row(
                    children: [
                      Text(
                        _eventData["endDate"] != null
                            ? "${_eventData["endDate"].month}/${_eventData["endDate"].day}/"
                                "${_eventData["endDate"].year}"
                            : 'End Date',
                        style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18),
                      ),
                      TextButton(
                        onPressed: () async {
                          if (_eventData["startDate"] == null) {
                            return _showErrorDialog(
                                "You must Select start Date first");
                          }
                          var val = await presentDatePicker(
                              context, _eventData["startDate"]);
                          if (val != null) {
                            setState(() {
                              _eventData["endDate"] = val;
                            });
                          }
                        },
                        child: Container(
                          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10),
                          decoration: BoxDecoration(
                              color: Colors.blue[900], shape: BoxShape.circle),
                          child: const FaIcon(FontAwesomeIcons.calendarAlt,
                              color: Colors.white),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
            Row(
              children: [
                Expanded(
                  child: RadioListTile(
                      value: false,
                      groupValue: privacy,
                      title: const Text('Public'),
                      onChanged: (val) {
                        setState(() => privacy = false);
                      }),
                ),
                Expanded(
                  child: RadioListTile(
                      value: true,
                      groupValue: privacy,
                      title: const Text('Private'),
                      onChanged: (val) {
                        setState(() => privacy = true);
                      }),
                )
              ],
            ),
            Container(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 5),
              child: Text(
                'Events are private by default',
                style: TextStyle(
                  color: Colors.blue[500],
                ),
                textAlign: TextAlign.center,
              ),
            ),
            const SizedBox(height: 20),
            ElevatedButton(
              onPressed: () {
                // Navigator.pushReplacementNamed(context, '/home');
                _submit();
              },
              // color: Colors.blue[700],
              // elevation: 6,s
              // shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
              //   borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(
              //     Radius.circular(10),
              //   ),
              // ),
              child: Container(
                width: 400,
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10),
                child: const Text(
                  'Create Event',
                  textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                  style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

I have tried adding changing to a ListView and even removed some of the widgets I thought were causing the issue but no luck so far.